# How to use the selenium (java) download file to change its name and folder downloads

Tags: java, selenium

I need to automate backup downloads
Perhaps you have ideas to do this using not only the Selenium
http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1502957258/14b25645/18276035.png

Answer (score 0):

Sine you're stating that selenium is not the requirement and you can consider alternatives I would propose the following way:

- if you know the file URL (or aware of how that URL can be generated) you can download the file straight from an URL. Check this post to figure out the details:

[How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

As per examples in the post, you can specify whatever the path and the name you want to be for a target file.

P.S. - You can use either browser embedded console or some third patrty sniffers to watch what are the URLs for the files and get aware how to build them on-the-fly in your script under different conditions.